# Debugging and difference search after refactoring in Visual Stduio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, macros, refactoring

I am involved in a c++ refactoring project and sometimes there are differences resulting, when there should be none. Currently, what I do is basically setting a breakpoint at some place, and then go through the program by F10/F11. The first problem is the size of the projects, traversing it takes a lot of time. Second, sometimes I have differences only in the end of a very big test sentences (say, 600 words), thus just getting to the different word is painfully slow.
1. Is it possible to write some kind of macro for Visual Studio, which will start from the breakpoint, then go step-by-step through the program until end while printing some fields?
2. Are there any neat tricks or tools to simplify the task?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Macros by using Tools>Macros>Macro IDE

If prefer the following method because it's faster for me.

You can record macros using `Tools>Macros>Record temporary macro`
Everything you type will then be recorded into a macro.

After you recorded what you want to be automated, you can edit the generated code by using `View>Other windows>Macro Explorer`. Your macro will be recorded in `MyMacros>RecordingModule>TemporaryMacro` in Macro Explorer window. If you right click that and select edit.

One way to test if the program is terminated:

```
While Not DTE.Debugger.CurrentProgram Is Nothing
```

Comment: Yes, I get it. The question is how to I say in macro "until program completes execution" or smth like that. I have
 Sub TemporaryMacro()
 DTE.Debugger.Go(True)
 DTE.Debugger.StepOver(True)
but I need to loop them. How can I do that?